# Why do I get 'Unexpected use of 'location' no-restricted-globals'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, eslint

In my reactjs code I got:

```
const {
  children,
  location: { pathname },
} = this.props;

let path = location.pathname;
```

Also using the react router module in this component. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this code

```
const {
  children,
  location: { pathname },
} = this.props;

let path = pathname;
```

Your `location` variable hasn't been defined in this block code so `eslint` thinks you use global variable

Answer (score 19):

In most/all web browsers, `location.reload()`, for example, is an alias for its fully-qualified name `window.location.reload()`.

You can test it in your browser by opening the dev tools pane console and typing in:

```
location.reload()
```

and

```
window.location.reload()
```

Both will trigger the page to refresh.

The ES Lint warning is effectively warning you that your code is relying on this alias, so it is plausible that in the future, the code could break suddenly, maybe if the alias became deprecated or some part of your tool chain operated in a manner that required usage of `window.`

In JavaScript, weird things can happen due to **variable-shadowing and closure**. It is possible that a `location` reference could be declared after and then such a reference to something like `location.reload()` would break with a message such as "no such method reload". This would be less likely to occur if you called the fully-qualified name `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `eslint` detected `location` is an element of `window`. So, try renaming your `props`:

```
const {
  children,
  myLocation: { pathname },
} = this.props;

let path = myLocation.pathname;
```

Reference:

- https://www.xul.fr/javascript/window-location.php
- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals